# $\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to show $M=\mathbb{R}$ with an atlas of chart $U=\mathbb{R}$, $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=2x$ when $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=3x$ when $x\leq 0$. Then $M$ is a smooth manifold which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

I got a part showing that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Also $M$ is Hausdorff and second countable. However I am having trouble showing $M$ is a smooth manifold.

Comment: How were you able to show that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ (presumably with the usual smooth structure) without knowing that $M$ is a smooth manifold?

Comment: @AlekosRobotis I assumed $M$ is a smooth manifold assuming I proved it.

Comment: Your atlas has only one chart $f$. The only transition map is the trivial one $f\circ f^{-1}=id$ which is clearly smooth.